# Additional dipping sauces for cheese fondue?

Tags: sauce, fondue

I have the fondue set pictured below (picture is of the box of the set):

[image]

I will be using it for the first time and see that on the picture of the box there are saucers with additional sauces/dips. I was wondering if this is really done for cheese fondue and what sauces would be appropriate for it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Seasoned Advice. Might those sauces be used when the unit was used for an oil-heated meat fondue?

Comment: @DanielGriscom, that's what I'm trying to find out. There isn't an instruction or anything just this picture on the box.

Comment: But you asked about Cheese Fondue; are you instead asking about either?

Comment: @DanielGriscom, I'm asking if such additional sauces/dips are served with cheese fondue or not.

Comment: I haven't heard of it; perhaps someone else will step in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was taught to make cheese fondue in Switzerland and also have a fondue cookbook and I've never seen or heard of sauces being used with cheese fondue. I would fill the containers with bread for cheese fondue, sauces for meat fondue and fruit and cake for chocolate fondue.

Comment: I'd second that.

Additionally I've heard of (crazy) people trying to do a "healthier" cheese fondue by using vegetables instead of bread.
I've never tried it myself as I love bread far too much :)

Answer (score 2):

No extra sauces for cheese fondue. Though it is common to have cornichons, pickled small onions and other pickles, as well as bacon, ham and whatever you like with melted cheese on the table. Not **in** the fondue! Some people like to use vegetables instead of bread, which I find a bit risky as you don't want lost pieces of such in the fondue. But you can have them on your plate and cover them with melted cheese if you like.